# How to fix Firefox stopping when using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Using Firefox 47.1 on Windows 10, I try to run the selenium example 2 given [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads). When starting the script, a new Firefox window opens and after a while the following error is shown in the PyCharm console:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpocxmjp8i If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Is there a SIMPLE way to fix this? I also did an upgrade to the latest python webdriver (version 2.53.6).

Replacing the line

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

with the line

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

in the example does it make work. So it works with chrome.

Comment: does it work from command line (not pycharm)

Comment: yes it does work from the command line...

Comment: I bet this is a compatibility issue. Try that with an older version of Firefox. Try FF 43 to be sure as it's known to be well supported.

Comment: Even if I were able to, how can I install an older version of firefox?

Comment: It is rather easy. You have a full listing officially provided by Mozilla here: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/. So just uninstall your current FF and install a new one. Once you have it installed, quickly go to settings and configure it not to download a new version automatically.

Comment: This will have impact on my whole work process. I will write it down, but I can't possibly do this right now. Maybe with a VM this is an option. Why must software be always bad....?

Comment: But thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: Its not the software that is bad, it is the interaction between pycharm and firefox.  To think that different code works so well together so often is actually quite amazing!

Comment: @Alex I am almost certain that you won;t be able to get away with that without downgrading your FF version. I am using a FF 33 for all my projects just to ensure compatibility. It is definitely not the best case scenario but it is a known limitation. (BTW, if you do not address me with "@" in your comments, I won't see them).

Comment: @Eugene: When I uninstall firefox, will I keep the settings, forms, passwords, bookmarks etc?

Comment: Please have a look at the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a compatibility issue. Note that there will always be a gap between the last browser version and Selenium support. For Firefox I would not recommend going above version 43.

All Firefox releases can be found [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/).

Of course downgrading the FF is quite an inconvenience and since you actually have to uninstall first, you might loose some of your data. There is a way however keep you stuff. Firefox profiles that store all your personal settings. There is a nice guide [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles) that explains how to export your settings, such as bookmarks, passwords and extensions.